# I'm getting this error: LWC component's @wire target property or method threw an error during value provisioning

Tags: lightning-web-components, list-view, lwc-wire-adapter, lightninglistview, lwc-wire-getlistui

I'm using getListUi wire adapter to get listViews of an object and trying to put it into a picklist. But I'm getting the following error.

render threw an error in 'c:showListView' [LWC component's @wire target property or method threw an error during value provisioning. Original error:
[Cannot read property 'lists' of undefined]]

This is the code:

```
import { LightningElement,wire,api,track } from 'lwc';
import PRODUCT_OBJECT from '@salesforce/schema/Product2';   
import { getListUi} from 'lightning/uiListApi';

export default class ShowPicklistValues extends LightningElement {
    @track selectedValue;
    @track allListViews;

    @wire(getListUi, {objectApiName: PRODUCT_OBJECT})
    wiredlistView({error,data}) {
    this.allListViews = data.lists;
    var listViewData = [];
    for(var i=0;i<this.allListViews.length;i++){
        listViewData.push({"label" : this.allListViews[i].label, "value" : this.allListViews[i].apiName});
    }
    this.allListViews = listViewData;
}

    handleChange(event) {
        this.value = event.detail.value;
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Welcome to SF Stack Exchange.

You are likely getting this error because an error must have occurred during your wire process.

From the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.data_wire_service_about):

> data (Any type)—The value supplied by the adapter.

> error (Error)—An error if the adapter wasn’t able to supply the requested data or if the adapter wasn’t found. Otherwise, this property is undefined.

In this case the `error` object came back instead of the `data`. Essentially since `data` did not come back your code attempts to execute `undefined.lists` which throws the error `[Cannot read property 'lists' of undefined]` you are seeing.

What you need to do is add an `if` statement to verify if `data` came back or not like so:

```
@wire(getListUi, {objectApiName: PRODUCT_OBJECT})
wiredlistView({error,data}) {
    if (data) {
        this.allListViews = data.lists;
        var listViewData = [];
        for(var i=0;i<this.allListViews.length;i++){
            listViewData.push({"label" : this.allListViews[i].label, "value" : this.allListViews[i].apiName});
    } else if (error) {
        console.log('An error has occurred:');
        console.log(error);
        // handle your error.
    }
}
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. It didn't even show any error on the console. It started working normally. I wonder why! Thanks a lot.